# p:commandLink doesn't react for method - MethodNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el, methodnotfound

I'm trying to delete object from table, but when I click on 'delete' button then nothing happens and it should invoke method which will delete this particular object. MethodNotFoundException appears and I have no idea why. Here is a code:

.xhtml:

```
                <p:column headerText="Imię">
                    <h:outputText value="#{client.firstName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nazwisko">
                    <h:outputText value="#{client.lastName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column>                  
                    <p:commandLink type="submit" value="Usuń"
                    style="font-size: 11px"
                        update="searcher:table:clientsTable" 
                        ajax="true"
                        actionListener="#{clientBean.deleteClient(client)}"
                        styleClass="btn btn-danger resized-font delete-btn"
                        icon="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>                                     
                    </p:commandLink>


                    <a href="klienci/#{client.ID}"
                    style="font-size: 11px"
                        class="btn btn-primary resized-font"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Informacje</a>

                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

method from ClientBean:

```
public void deleteClient(Client client){
    clientDao.delete(client);
}
```

exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.firanycrm.controller.ClientBean@14b77a2a.deleteClient(com.firanycrm.model.Client)
```

Comment: did you try to add an `Ajax` event ?!?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put `p:commandLink` type to `submit`, and try to add  `process="@this"` to your `p:commandLink`

```
<p:commandLink value="Delete" 
               update="table" 
               actionListener="#{clientBean.deleteClient(client)}" 
               process="@this" />
```